# Picamera mmal Error

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I was using my Picamera but there was Error like this:

> mmal: Cannot read cameara info, keeping the defaults for OV5647 mmal:
>   mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component ‘vc.ril.camera’
>   (1:ENOMEM) mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create
>   component ‘vc.ril.camera’ (1) mmal: Failed to create camera component
>   mmal: main: Failed to create camera component mmal: Camera is not
>   detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed
>   correctly

So far I did:

- update and upgrade my raspiberry pi and than reboot
- update firmware and than reboot
- change camera config and than reboot
- check connecter

Comment: Please, add your code here.

Comment: Can you verify the camera unit is working? I had a weird error one time like this and the camera unit ended up being dead

Comment: I found that when I connected my camera there was no light.

Comment: Does it died? :(

Answer (score 0):

That is the same error one receives when a camera module is not even plugged in.

So could be a physical problem, try re-seating the connectors, check cable orientation. Possibly try testing camera on a different Raspberry PI all together. Check the following [settings](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)

Comment: same error happened but i can use `libcamera-jpeg -o test.jpg` to get photo,that maybe not means physical problem